# PostgreSQL / Redshift - prevent access to system views

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I am working with Redshift (which is based on PostgreSQL) and need to create a user that is restricted to a particular database schema.  They also need to be locked out of the system views.  I ran the following on the database cluster:

```
revoke create on schema information_schema from public
revoke usage on schema information_schema from public

revoke create on schema pg_catalog from public
revoke usage on schema pg_catalog from public

revoke create on schema public from public
revoke usage on schema public from public
```

Next, I create a user and run as that user:

```
SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION someUser
```

Then I try to access some system views:

```
select * from information_schema.tables
```

> An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
>   select * from information_schema.tables
>   ERROR: permission denied for schema information_schema [SQL State=42501]

```
select * from pg_catalog.pg_user
```

> An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
>   select * from pg_catalog.pg_user
>   ERROR: permission denied for schema pg_catalog [SQL State=42501]

So far so good -- the user cannot poke around in the system views.

But for some reason when I run the following it succeeds:

```
select * from pg_user
```

In other words, if the user tries to query pg_user without specifying the pg_catalog schema, they are able to see the users in the system.

Any ideas on how to prevent this?

Comment: I think you need to revoke those privileges for each and every view.

Comment: OK, that approach does work.  I just ran the following to generate a REVOKE ALL FROM PUBLIC on all pg_catalog views: SELECT 'revoke all on '||viewname||' from public;' FROM pg_views WHERE schemaname = 'pg_catalog'.  I didn't have to do that on the pg_catalog tables because the prior revoke I did on the pg_catalog schema took care of those.  For some reason, the pg_catalog *views* need to be explicitly revoked.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @RedTailedHawk If you have permissions to select from a view, you have the implicit permission to select all tables that the view references when selecting through the view. That's why you have to revoke from views even if you've already revoked direct access to the underlying tables.